# $.getJSON not executing success callback for WCF service call

Tags: jquery, wcf, getjson

I am calling my WCF service hosted on local IIS through jQuery using $.getJSON().

look at my java script code

```
getTestRunsByProject: function (projectKey) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var link = scnfg.ServiceURL + '/GetTestRunsForProject/' + projectKey + '?callback=?';
        $.getJSON(link, function (results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    },
```

where I have appended ?callback=? at the end of service url because I was getting empty response with 200 status code in firebug console tab with red text; though service was functional.

when url is modified with the string ?callback=? then I am not getting service call entry in firebug console tab instead I found the service call details in Net tab of firebug which contains the desired response from service.

I am calling this function with following script code

```
$.when(serviceapi.getTestRunsByProject("W6")).then(function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            lstTestRuns = data;
        }
    });
```

Now with ?callback=? it does return response from service call **when checked in firebug Net tab** but success callback of $.getJSON doesn't get triggered i.e. it does not returns $.Deffered() object. And there is confusion with usage of ?callback=? that why service call entry not get recorded in firebug console tab.

can anybody help in this? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you install an error handler and see if jQuery is reporting a specific error condition?  Does your web service specifically support JSONP which packages the result into a javascript function call?

Comment: Also, you don't need to create your own deferred object here.  `$.getJSON()` returns a promise compatible object that will automatically get resolved or failed by the ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your reply. I have added attribute to service contract to return response in json format as follows     [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetTestRunsForProject/{projectKey}")]
        List<dcTestRun> GetTestRunsForProject(string projectKey); please tell me if I need to do anything more than this?

Comment: JSONP format is different than JSON.  You have to explicitly know which one is being requested by the client and generate the right one.  Using `callback=` in the URL usually means JSONP for cross domain usage.

Comment: I don't specifically require JSONP format using callback=. But when I remove this I will get emty response as I already describe in problem statement. So now if I need to reply on JSON format only by removing callback= then how can I achieve my service call to return required response. Or else If I need to go with JSONP then how can I add support to WCF service?

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey thanks for hints from your comment Number 1 & 3, for which I searched & found [this link](http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery) which gives me idea about what I was doing wrong. I was missing the crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled attribute on service site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ?callback=? I was achieving cross domain call to my service but from service end I was returning plain json format result. So in this case service client was requesting the data in JSONP format where my service returning JSON formatted data. With the jfriend00 suggestion I searched for how to implement JSONP  mechanism & found useful [this](http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery) link.

Referring this link I come to know that I need to set binding configuration for my service endpoint to enable corss domain call. For this I added following markup to my service configuration file

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJSONP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and updated my endpoint definition to use this binding configuration as follows

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IAuFaitDashboard" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJSONP" behaviorConfiguration="MySetting">
```

Then my java script getTestRunsByProject function started executing as expected.